# javascript sort function sorting wrong

Tags: javascript, sorting

Hello I have a textbox having values like

```
<input type="hidden" value="2,1,4,5,3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12" class="sortvalues" id="1_1_parent">
```

Now what I want to take the value of this textbox, want to split the values to array and then as last result I need a sorted array.

What I have done.

```
 allsortedValues =  $(".sortvalues").val();
 allsortedValues = allsortedValues.split(",");
 allsortedValues = allsortedValues.sort();
```

When I check the array

```
 console.log(allsortedValues);
```

It shows

```
  1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Sorting array as `1, 10, 11, 12, 2.....`

I have even used

```
allsortedValues = allsortedValues.split(",").map(function(x){return parseInt(x)});
```

before applying sort and in other case I have even used `parseInt` like

```
for(var i = 0; i < allsortedValues.length; i++) {

   allsortedValues[i] = parseInt(allsortedValues[i]);
}
```

before applying sort but in all cases result is same. Will some one guide what am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/sort-not-working-with-integers
It is possible duplicated

Comment: Your sort is working fine, javascript is treating your input as strings instead of numbers hence the unexpected behavior. See @Pointy's answer for a proper solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll have to pass in a comparator function that converts the strings to numbers:

```
allsortedvalues = allsortedvalues.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (+a) - (+b);
});
```

If there's a chance that some of your array entries aren't nicely-formatted numbers, then your comparator would have to get more complicated.

The construction `(+a)` involves the unary `+` operator, which doesn't do anything if `a` is already a number. However if `a` is *not* a number, the result of `+a` will be either the value of `a` when *interpreted* as a number, or else `NaN`.  A string is *interpreted* as a number in the obvious way, by being examined and parsed as a string representation of a number. A boolean value would be converted as `false -> 0` and `true -> 1`. The value `null` becomes `0`, and `undefined` is `NaN`. Finally, an object reference is interpreted as a number via a call to its `valueOf()` function, or else `NaN` if that doesn't help.

It's equivalent to use the Number constructor, as in `Number(a)`, if you like. It does exactly the same thing as `+a`. I'm a lazy typist.

Comment: I guess the `(+a)` stuff might not be strictly necessary, but I find it nice to highlight what's going on a little.

Comment: `(+)`'ses look quite confusing. I'd suggest `Number(a)-Number(b)` if you want to be explicit.

Comment: @thg435 agree, I prefer human language :)

Comment: Personally I think just `return a - b;//compare two numbers` with a comment is clear enough.

Comment: `(+a)` is just using coersion, something you should understand if you're writing JavaScript. This comment thread has me wondering, though, is `(+a)` congruent to `Number(a)`? That is, does the interpreter do the same thing in either case?

Comment: @JamesSumners sorry to be almost 5 years late, but yes `+a` will do precisely the same thing as `Number(a)`.

Comment: @Pointy just want to comment, for a lazy typist, you sure are not lazy to type all those epxlanation about +a being equivalent to Number(a). If you use Number(a) in your code, you don't need to explain that much :)

Answer (score 14):

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting
> them to strings and comparing strings in lexicographic ("dictionary"
> or "telephone book," not numerical) order. For example, "80" comes
> before "9" in lexicographic order, but in a numeric sort 9 comes
> before 80.
>
> To compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can simply subtract b from a:

```
function compareNumbers(a, b)
{
  return a - b;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Erm, I answered the actual question: "Javascript not sorting correctly, what am I doing wrong?" That doesn't necessitate providing the correct sorting function. _That_ is in the linked documentation, which the OP clearly should read.